# Does the inner product attain a maximum on the given set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $y = ( y_1, y_2, y_3 ) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the sets
$$
P := \{(p_1, p_2, p_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : p_1+p_2+p_3 = 1, \ p_1, p_2, p_3 > 0 \},
$$
$$
\bar{P}:= \{(p_1, p_2, p_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : p_1+p_2+p_3 = 1, \ p_1, p_2, p_3 \geq 0 \},
$$
$$
S_y := \{ (p_1, p_2, p_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \langle y, p \rangle = 1 \},
$$
and the mapping $F$ given by
$$
\mathbb{R}^3 \ni x \mapsto \langle y, x \rangle.
$$
I am trying to show the following two statements:

> 1. The mapping $F \vert_{\bar{P} \cap S_y}$ attains a maximum on $\bar{P} \cap S_y$.
> 2. If $F \vert_{P \cap S_y}$ attains a maximum on $P \cap S_y$, then $F \vert_{\bar{P} \cap S_y}$ is constant on $\bar{P} \cap S_y$.

I think the fist statement can be argued as follows:

$\bar{P}$ is closed and bounded, and $S_y$ is closed, so the intersection is closed and bounded, hence compact. Since $F \vert_{\bar{P} \cap S_y}$ is continuous, the first statement is true. Is this correct?

And how can one show the second statement? Is it possible that the 2nd statement should rather be modified to the following:

> 2. If $F \vert_{\bar{P} \cap S_y}$ attains a maximum on $P \cap S_y$, then $F \vert_{\bar{P} \cap S_y}$ is constant on $\bar{P} \cap S_y$

In any case, if necessary, one may assume that $y_1, y_2, y_3 \geq 0$.

Comment: What if $y=\alpha(1,1,1),\alpha\ne 0$? Then even the planes $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$ and $\langle y,p\rangle=1$ don't intersect, they are parallel and disjoint.

Comment: @PinkyWay I should have mentioned the assumption $P \cap S_y \neq \emptyset$.